# Expect programming:How to expect a particular string

Tags: tcl, expect

I have logged in the CUCM then we are trying to execute one command which is coming correct, but by the Expected value we are not able to execute the second command.
first we are doing like this:-

```
send -i $install_id "utils ctl set-cluster mixed-mode\r\n"
puts "we are hitting yes &&&&&&&&&&"
expect {
    -i $install_id -re ".*" {
        send -i  $install_id "y\r"
        puts "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ we are inside...."
    }
}
puts "we are done %%%%%%%%%%"
return 1
```

here first command `send -i $install_id "utils ctl set-cluster mixed-mode\r\n"` is getting executed sucessfully , but it is not going inside the expect loop.

the output of first command is something like:-

```
admin:utils ctl set-cluster mixed-mode
This operation will set the cluster to Mixed mode. Do you want to   continue? (y/n):
```

after this the cursor will be in next line where i have to give y and enter, the output statment inside expect is also not getting printed

Comment: You can try to execute these commands in the verbose mode. Add 'exp_internal 1' before the first send.

Comment: i didnt get...as i am new to these programming...what exactly you are trying   to add

Comment: Are you running an except script or only commands inside expect interface?

Comment: if it's a script, I suggest to add the string 'exp_internal 1' as the first command of the script

Comment: ya it;s a script only...i tried still it is giving same error

Comment: This command only turns on internal expect logging. Could you, please, provide the full output of the script with exp_internal 1? Maybe we'll see why you get this error.

Comment: we are inside is getting printed but enter is not getting pressed

Comment: This means that expect is still waiting for something. You can stop the script by pressing Ctrl + C. What is in the console?

Comment: Nothing came in the log but that enter didn't got executed

Comment: You can also try to use '-i $install_id -re "continue?"' as parameters for expect.

Comment: i tried this also but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'd be doing something like:

```
expect {
    -i $install_id
    -ex "continue? (y/n):" {
        puts "I FOUND A CONTINUE PROMPT"
        send -i $install_id "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "$thePrompt" {
        puts "I FOUND A SYSTEM PROMPT"
    }
}
```

Like that, it would only stop that `expect` once the command has finished, but it will respond to the `continue` prompt and keep going (because `exp_continue`). In this case, the `-ex` option is suitable as that matches a literal string, a great convenience when the thing that you are looking for contains multiple regular expression metacharacters (`?`, `(` and `)`).

And change `"$thePrompt"` for the right thing to actually match the prompt, of course.

Comment: i tried the way u suggested but getting this error as :- 
    # An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime       Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x003ef025, pid=24279, tid=4150630080
#
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (10.0-b23 mixed mode, s      sharing linux-x86)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libc.so.6+0x13a025]
    #

Comment: @user3388407 That's strange. Cool story, bro.

Comment: Any other suggestion for this

Answer (score 0):

Use autoinspect(1).

Start it, then run all your commands manually, inspect the `script.exp` file it created. It should have recorded the exact matched strings, in case there is some weird shell coloring going on which makes you missing your expected string but having no idea why.